# Identify face of raycast intersection on BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

The intersection object (returned by `raycaster.intersectObject()`) has `face` and `faceIndex` properties. However these properties are null if the intersected object is a `BufferGeometry`. On the other hand the `point` property works as expected.

Is there any way to determine which face of the `BufferGeometry` was hit? There is obviously no `faces` array in `BufferGeometry` but knowing (for example) the indices of points in `position` attribute defining the hit face would be great help.

(I can certainly use some math since I know the coordinates of all the points, but that would kill my performance on large geometry)

Comment: I think you answered your own question, no? You can always modify the code to return whatever you want, and propose an enhancement if you determine it is useful.

Comment: I was wondering whether there is a more elegant way, maybe setting some flag to enable face identification similar to ordinary Geometry, that would no doubt be much better than anything I can come up with. Determining the face myself is at best a fallback solution.

Comment: Have a look at `Raycaster.js`, if you haven't already, and you will see what it computes.

Comment: FWIW, I had the same experience (using the SEA3D loader). As soon as I changed the parser to only create Geometry (not BufferedGeometry) from the .sea3d file, things began to work again. +1 for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the relevant code can be found in `THREE.Mesh`; if you look at `Raycaster.js`, you'll see that `THREE.Raycaster` mostly delegates to the (undocumented, abstract) `raycast` method of `THREE.Object3D`. [Various subclasses of `Object3D` implement this method](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/search?q=raycast), including `Mesh`.

The [relevant lines from `THREE.Mesh#raycast`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1769fbfc6c994b51a54c15a5c096855fd3cb8a1a/src/objects/Mesh.js#L98-L182) show that the intersection objects look like this:

```
{
    distance: distance,
    point: intersectionPoint,
    indices: [ a, b, c ],
    face: null,
    faceIndex: null,
    object: this
}
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` are the indices of the vertices on the intersected face.

This means that to get the indices of the vertices comprising the intersected face, you can do:

```
var intersect = raycaster.intersectObject(scene);
if (intersect != null) {
    var faceIndices;
    if (intersect.face != null) {
        faceIndices = [ face.a, face.b, face.c ];
    } else if (intersect.indices != null) {
        faceIndices = intersect.indices
    }

    // do something with the faceIndices
}
```

three.js r68

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the question is kind of old and I don't think Three.js could do that at the time. Btw. the (than) raycaster worked in linear time so I eventualy used GPU picking.

Comment: Sure; I'd just struggled with the same thing recently and thought others might benefit.